# How to enter data in the Windows Authentication pop up in Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I am writing E2E(Using Protractor) test cases for an Angular app. Whenever I hit the application URL, it asks me for Windows authentication and I am unable to enter the Username and Password in the Authentication popup. Is there any way to fill the pop-up form my test case file? Please suggest.

Comment: Edited the grammar and sentence structure to make it more clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is basic HTTP Authentication that you are looking for - This when you see a windows pop-up when you manually open the url - You can avoid that by two ways

1.Change `baseUrl = http://example.com` TO `baseUrl = http://username:password@example.com`

2. Or you can have a `browser.get('http://username:password@example.com')`

This will do the basic HTTP Authentication for you !!!

Comment: What if it's NLTM?